# Is there any REST API to Approve/Deny Workday Inbox Task

Tags: workday-api

I am looking for the Workday API's to approve or deny the particular inbox task through postman using user specific authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you look for the PUT My Inbox Task in the documentation, it will show you how to do this. You'll need to get the inbox tasks first so you know what Workday ID's need to be called.

Here's the link to that section of the documentation: [https://doc.workday.com/r/wsiU0cnNjCc_k7shLNxLEA/nOhIibUZE~tGCRAdk6f3Cw](https://doc.workday.com/r/wsiU0cnNjCc_k7shLNxLEA/nOhIibUZE%7EtGCRAdk6f3Cw)